# Users/Passwords in Rebol 3 Schemes

Tags: url-routing, rebol, rebol3

In the port spec below I'm attempting to parse a URL to determine user, pass, host and path. User/Pass values are optional, but I'd like to set default values for each if not present.

However if the user/pass are not there, `user`/`pass` are omitted from the `port/spec` object—why is this?

```
>> read sch://foo/bar.r
PORT/SPEC is an object of value: 
   title           string!   "Wee Scheme" 
   scheme          word!     sch 
   ref             url!      sch://foo/bar.r 
   path            string!   "/bar.r" 
   host            string!   "foo" 

>> read sch://foo:bar@foo/bar.r
PORT/SPEC is an object of value: 
   title           string!   "Wee Scheme" 
   scheme          word!     sch 
   ref             url!      sch://foo:bar@foo/bar.r 
   path            string!   "/bar.r" 
   pass            string!   "bar" 
   user            string!   "foo" 
   host            string!   "foo"
```

Also, in drafting this question, I made an error in the scheme and bound the parse rule to the `port`, not the `port/spec`—how are the values then set in the `port/spec` object?

Spec:

```
sys/make-scheme [
    name: 'sch
    title: "Wee Scheme"
    actor: [
        read: func [port][
            parse port/spec/ref use [chars][
                chars: charset [#"a" - #"z" #"A" - #"Z" #"0" - #"9" "-_!+%.,"]

                bind [
                    "sch://" [
                        copy user some chars #":"
                        copy pass some chars #"@"
                        | (user: 'mince pass: 'tatties)
                    ]
                    copy host some chars
                    copy path [some [#"/" any chars]]
                    end
                ] port
            ]
            ? port/spec
        ]
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make-scheme https://github.com/rebol/r3/blob/master/src/mezz/sys-ports.r#L254 uses as default spec system/standard/port-spec-net which does not have a user and pass.

```
>> system/standard/port-spec-net
== make object! [
    title: none
    scheme: none
    ref: none
    path: none
    host: none
    port-id: 80
]
```

So, if you want user and pass even when not passed in the spec, you have to create your own spec like this https://github.com/rebol/r3/blob/master/src/mezz/prot-http.r#L417 and set them there.

Comment: So where does user/pass come from then in the port/spec object—I didn't add them. And what happens to 'mince and 'tatties?

Comment: parse-url captures the user and password from the url provided to 'open.

Comment: See make-port which calls parse-url on a url! https://github.com/rebol/r3/blob/master/src/mezz/sys-ports.r#L32

Answer (score 3):

There are no `user` or `pass` fields in the standard port specs because many port schemes don't even have users or passwords as a concept. If you *need* to have a user and pass every time, use your own port spec prototype when building ports, as Graham suggested.

However, you might also consider using `select` on the port spec in your scheme. The `select` function in R3 works on objects as well, and just returns `none` when the word you are selecting isn't currently defined in the object. That is a helpful shortcut we added that you can use throughout R3.

Don't feel that you have to include every optional word in your spec object prototype. Every word you include in the spec prototype gets added to every resultant spec whether it applies or not. If you have default values for missing words, you might as well add those defaults to the prototype spec, though be careful with default series values since they might get modified. But for words that are really optional, like `user` and `pass`, consider leaving them out of the prototype to save memory overhead and just use `select` instead.

Comment: So where does user/pass come from then in the port/spec object—I didn't add them. And what happens to 'mince and 'tatties?